# C/C++ - copying by value arrays that are part of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

consider the following C++ struct:

```
typedef struct Person {
    std::string name;
    std::string children[MAX_NUM_CHILDREN];
} Person;
```

The question is, what happens in the following scenario:

```
void do_something(const Person& p) {
    Person person_copy = p;
}
```

The question is whether the `children` array of `p`, which is actually a member of type `std::string*`, is going to be copied as a pointer, or is every string in the `children` array going to be copied by value using the copy constructor?

Comment: You do not need to `typedef` a `struct` in c++. `struct Person { ... };` is sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [...] the `children` array of `p`, which is actually a member of type `std::string*` [...]

`children` is an array of `MAX_NUM_CHILDREN` strings, not a pointer. All of its elements will be copied over to `person_copy.children` by `Person`'s copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there the array will decay in this example so the content will be copied.

`T[]` and `T*` are different but `T[]` can decay to `T*` (you can look for the array decaying rules).

Your `Person` struct should be declared like that:

```
struct Person {
    std::string name;
    std::string children[MAX_NUM_CHILDREN];
};
```

That's shorter and that's the C++ way.

BTW, the copy constructor will be called because this is an assignment initialisation but it's better use the `Person p(p2);` (or `Person p{p2}` with C++11 compatible compiler) initialisation form.

Comment: `I don't think there the array will decay in this example` Of course it won't. If arrays within objects decayed to pointers during their declaration, it would make C/C++ useless. Decay only occurs in cases like assigning to a pointer, including the typical case of conversion when passing a raw array to a function.

Comment: no but it could have decay when passing ``Person`` to the function (that's why I think it's better to use ``std::array``: there are no risk of decay). (C and C++ have some weird corner cases so I wouldn't have been surprised)

Comment: Bare arrays can only decay when they are named directly, not when they are part of some other object that is passed around or whatever. Again, the latter would make the language absurd.